# Angular - sequential execute code after for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, angular-promise

Please let me know if I have to provide any more code or explanations.

I am trying to execute some code after I call a service method inside a for loop. I tried two different ways.

In 1st method, the `console.log('1st After for loop')` which after the for loop is printing before it prints the console.log(data)

In 2nd method, the `console.log('2nd- After for loop')` is never printing.

I want to loop through the list. Validate each item. If not validation not successful, show ask for a confirmation. If user selects Yes, the call save method.

Code snippet #1:

```
save() {
  this.selectRowData.forEach(async s => {
    this.myService.validate(s.id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if(data) {
         this.myService.confirm('Please confirm..', 'Selected Rule do not match expected rules. \n Do you want to continue? ', 'Yes', 'No')
      .then((confirmed) => {
        if(confirmed) {
          console.log("User selected: Yes");
         this.myService.save();
        } else {
          console.log("User selected: No");
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log("Error...");
      });
    }, (error: any) => {
      alert("Error Linking Lot");
    });
  });
  console.log('1st After for loop');
}
```

Code snippet #2:

```
async save() {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    this.selectRowData.forEach(async s => {
      let validateData = await this.myService.validate1(s.id);
      console.log(validateData);
    });

  });
  console.log('2nd- After for loop');
}
```

**service.ts**

```
validate(id: string): Observable < boolean > {
  return this.httpClient.get < boolean > ('/RestWeb/validate?id=' + id);
}

validate1(id: string) {
  return this.httpClient.get < boolean > ('/RestWeb/validate?id=' + id).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Try using setTimeout() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various issues with your implementation.

Issues with the `save` method:

1. You're using `async` which only works on methods that return a promise.
2. You're calling `validate` method on the `myService` in the callback method, which returns an <strike>`Promise`</strike> `Observable`.
3. You could've used used await in there if the validate method returned a `Promise`. But it returns an `Observable`.
4. `forEach` runs synchronously but the `myService.validate` method runs asynchronously and so will the callback method inside the success callback to the `.subscribe` method.

That's the reasons why it's logging `'1st After for loop'` before logging the results.

Issue with the `async save` method:

You're `await`ing the `new Promise` inside the method but not `reject`ing or `resolve`ing that promise.

That's probably why the `'2nd- After for loop'` isn't even logging.

A better way would be to either use the RxJS **[`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)** operator to join all the Observables returned by the `myService.validate` method and then log inside the success callback to the `subscribe` method. Something like this:

```
forkJoin(
  this.selectRowData.map(({ id }: any) => this.myService.validate(id))
).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log('save:: ', data);
    console.log('save:: 1st After for loop');
  },
  (error: any) => {
    alert('save:: Error Linking Lot');
  }
);
```

Alternatively, if you want to go with the `promise` approach(which wouldn't make much sense since you're using RxJS), you could also use **[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)**, `await` it and then log the results, and then the message. Something like this:

```
async saveAsync() {
  const responses = await Promise.all(
    this.selectRowData.map(({ id }: any) => this.myService.validate1(id))
  );
  console.log('saveAsync:: ', responses);
  console.log('saveAsync:: 2nd- After for loop');
}
```

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-promise-or-rxjs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your ref. Please check the console for the result.

Comment: it's unnecesary use the spread operator (the `...`) both in `const observables` and in forkJoin. use simple: `observables=this.selectRowData.map(x=>this.myService.validate(s.id))` and `forkJoin(observables)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. upvoted for now. it gave me a lot of idea now. I tried with my code, it is working. I am sorry, I didn't explain the entire scenario. Now I have updated the code and what I actually want. with my requirement, I am still stuck. when I try to call save for each element, I am not getting the result from validate method.

Comment: @SK. we're supposed to keep threads focused here on StackOverflow. So I'd recommend reverting the question update, closing this loop, and asking a new question with this issue.

Comment: Sure, asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629174