# Execute code after executing everything for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

Please let me know if I have to provide any more code or explanations.

I am trying to execute validate, if validation not successful, confirm(Yes/No), and then save method for all selected rows in a for loop.

**Requirement:** I have show a success/failure message after looping through all selected rows. That means:

If 5 rows are selected (2 are valid and 3 are not valid) - got from myService.validate

It will ask if you still want to continue for 3 not valid records - myConfirmService.confirm

It should save those 2 valid records

If user selects 'Yes' in confirm window (lets says for 2 records), then it should save these 2 as well.

At the end - it will display success/failure message - alertService.success

**What I want:**

To fulfil what I described in the requirement

and The success/failure message should display only once after all record saved

**component.ts:**

```
save() {
    this.selectRowData.forEach(async s => {
        this.myService.validate(s.id).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data == false) {
                this.myConfirmService
                    .confirm('Please confirm..', 'Selected Part do not match expected part data. \n Do you still want to continue? ', 'Yes', 'No')
                    .then((confirmed) => {
                        if(confirmed) {
                            console.log("User selected: Yes");
                            this.myService.savePart();
                        } else {
                            console.log("User selected: No");
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(() => {
                        console.log("Error...");
                    });
            } else {
                console.log("Selected Rule matches expected rules for: " + s.designChangeClass);
                this.saveModelPart(s);
            }
        }, (error: any) => {
            alert("Error Linking Lot");
        });
    });
    console.log('1st After for loop');
    this.alertService.success('Part saved successfully.')
}
```

**service.ts**

```
validate(id: string): Observable < boolean > {
    return this.httpClient.get < boolean > ('/RestWeb/validate?id=' + id);
}
      
validate1(id: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get < boolean > ('/RestWeb/validate?id=' + id).toPromise();
}
  
savePart(item: Part): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post('/RestService/savePart', item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```js
//Change method to async
async save() {
  //Create custom index variable, since for of loop doesn't have one
  let ind = 0;
  //Use for of instead of forEach
  for (const eachRow of this.selectRowData) {
    //await until API validated
    const isValid = await this.myService.validate(eachRow.id).toPromise();
    if (!isValid) {
      //await again if it is not valid and until user confirmed
      const isConfirmed = await this.myConfirmService.confirm('Please confirm..', 'Selected Part do not match expected part data. \n Do you still want to continue? ', 'Yes', 'No').toPromise();
      if (isConfirmed) {
        //await again until record saved as user selected yes in confirm
        console.log('User selected: Yes');
        await this.myService.savePart().toPromise();
      } else {
        console.log('User selected: No');
      }
    } else {
      console.log(
        'Selected Rule matches expected rules for: ' +
          eachRow.designChangeClass
      );
      this.saveModelPart(eachRow);
    }
    //Finally display message after loop is finished
    if (ind === this.selectRowData.length - 1) {
      this.alertService.success('Part saved successfully.');
    }
    ind++;
  }
}
```

Although this solution works but is not a good practice to do it in this way,
Instead, modify API to accept multiple `ids` for validation, and display a table of records (success and failures) along with buttons to confirm for continuation.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me. Unfortunately API is not my control. I tried your solution. I still have the problem. I can see the success message even before I hit Yes/No in the conform box. That means if I have 5 records and 2 of then are valid, I can see the message after those 2 save and before other 3 confirmed

Comment: I will try this. I also did something similar like that last night. :)

Comment: I found that `forEach` just executes the function and does not `await` it to end, Instead, it moves to the next iteration. This [article](https://itnext.io/why-async-await-in-a-foreach-is-not-working-5f13118f90d) is good.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fork join in this case, so it makes all calls and get the response on a arrays of booleans

```js
save() {
  let obsArray = this.selectRowData.map(s=>this.myService.validate(s.id));
  forkJoin(obsArray).subscribe(
    (arrayBoolean)=>{
       // do your logic here
    }
  )
 
}
```

See https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin for more info

//EDIT: misspelled

Comment: Is forJoin a typo?

Answer (score 0):

For what i understood your trying to save only valid data with an extra of user confirmation. One Part is a little confusing because you are trying to confirm valid data that does not match and expected rule but apart from that, i would do something like this.

**Component method:**

```
  rowValidation() {
    this.selectRowData.forEach( rowElement => {
      this.myService.validate(rowElement.id).subscribe( data => {
        //call comfirm service method.
      })
    })
  }
```

**Confirm Service method:**

```
  confirm() {
    //ask for confirmation code
    //if(yes) call myservice.save
    //else log "no"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright friend... your logic is actually a bit complicated, so it will be much easier to follow if we break it up into smaller parts.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you need to:

1. Validate each row
2. If any fail validation, ask user if they want to save anyway
3. Save data (*valid rows, and possibly invalid rows*)

Starting with the end in mind, we could do something like this:

```js
  save() {
    of(this.selectRowData).pipe(
      switchMap(this.validateRows),
      switchMap(rows => this.promptUserIfSomeInvalid(rows).pipe(
        switchMap(saveInvalidRows => {
          const rowsToSave = saveInvalidRows ? rows : rows.filter(r => r.isValid);
          
          return forkJoin(rowsToSave.map(this.myService.savePart));
        })
      ))
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Here we start the observable chain with [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of).

You may have noticed all the [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)s!!! If you aren't familiar, `switchMap` is a nifty operator that will subscribe to an observable for you, and emit its emissions. It also takes care of unsubscribing from this "inner observable" automatically.

What you need to know about `switchMap`:

> Inside `switchMap`, you pass a function that returns an observable.

The first `switchMap` receives the row data and subscribes to an observable that calls your validation observable.  `this.validateRows` returns an observable that emits the array of rows, each with an additional boolean property indicating if the validation for that row passed.

`switchMap` #2 subscribes to an observable that emits a boolean indicating whether or not invalid rows should be saved.

`switchMap` #3 subscribes to an observable that makes all your api calls to save the appropriate rows.

[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) creates an observable that emits when its array of source observables all complete.  So, we are simply `map`ping the rows, to observables (`this.myService.savePart()`).

Here are the implementations of the methods used above:

```js
  private validateRows(rows: Row[]) {
    return forkJoin(rows.map(row => this.myService.validate(row.id))).pipe(
      map(this.appendIsValidFieldToRows(rows)),
    );
  }

  private promptUserIfSomeInvalid(rows: ValidatedRow[]) {
    const invalidCount = rows.filter(r => !r.isValid).length;
    const message = `Would you like to save ${invalidCount} rows?`;

    return rows.some(r => !r.isValid)
      ? from(this.myConfirmService.confirm(message))
      : of(true);
  }

  private appendIsValidFieldToRows(rows: Row[]) {
    return (isValidArray: boolean[]) => rows.map((r, i) => ({...r, isValid: isValidArray[i]})) as ValidatedRow[];
  }
```

Here is a [Non-Functional StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67629174?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that I used as a scratch pad to avoid typing mistakes. It may be useful for seeing the typings or even throw some fake data into for testing.

I'm not 100% sure I understood your exact intention, but I hope this gives you a push in the right direction.

The main takeaways are:

- Break code into smaller functions
- Utilize [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to avoid nested subscriptions.
- Instead of using `forEach` loops, use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array of rows into an array of Observables, that you can then pass to `forkJoin`

Note: I left out your error catching because this answer was getting pretty long and the question didn't really focus on that aspect.  However, with the logic broken down into separate functions, it makes it easy to add in a [`catchError`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) in the necessary places.